# TypeOrm NestJs Typescript Data Types Best Practices

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on a project where I have on the backend NestJs, TypeOrm for working with a database (postgres) and all this in typescript. Every time when it is necessary to make some changes in the database, for example, add a field or change it, I am faced with the fact that I have to change/add the data type in a very large number of places. These are typescript interfaces, NestJS responseDto/requestDto/updateDto, Typeorm Entity, and so on. It can be very time consuming. Is this ok and what are the best practices to reduce the time spent on changing types?

Comment: Can you give an example of each of these and how they relate within your app? Usually, you want one model that represents your database object and can be reused in other places.